# How to use three different columns in a join to get only two columns in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables one mentioning the start and end time of an event and corresponding value and other having the value recorded at midnight daily.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    id integer,
    date_strt timestamp,
    date_end timestamp,
    strt_unit integer,
    end_unit integer
);

INSERT INTO table1 (id, date_strt, date_end,strt_unit,end_unit)
VALUES
    (1, '2023-10-27 12:00:00','2023-10-31 12:00:00', 5,72),
    (2, '2023-10-30 12:15:00','2023-11-02 00:00:00', 78,90);
    
    
CREATE TABLE table2 (
    id integer,
    dates timestamp,
    unit integer
);

INSERT INTO table2 (id, dates, unit)
VALUES
    (1, '2023-10-28 00:00:00', 55),
    (1, '2023-10-29 00:00:00', 60),
    (1, '2023-10-30 00:00:00', 65),
    (1, '2023-10-31 00:00:00', 70),
    (2, '2023-10-30 00:00:00', 75),
    (2, '2023-10-31 00:00:00', 80),
    (2, '2023-11-01 00:00:00', 85),
    (2, '2023-11-02 00:00:00', 90);
```

I want to obtain data set like this where I obtain difference in data of each day at midnight 00:00:00 hours starting from the start date to end date mentioned in table 1 by using the date available at table 2.

```
id start_time          start_value    end_time            end_value
1, '2023-10-27 12:00:00', 5,      '2023-10-28 00:00:00', 55
1, '2023-10-28 00:00:00', 55,     '2023-10-29 00:00:00', 60
1, '2023-10-29 00:00:00', 60,     '2023-10-30 00:00:00', 65
1, '2023-10-30 00:00:00', 65,     '2023-10-31 00:00:00', 70
1, '2023-10-31 00:00:00', 70,     '2023-10-31 12:00:00', 72
2, '2023-10-30 12:15:00', 78,     '2023-10-31 00:00:00', 80    
2, '2023-10-31 00:00:00', 80,     '2023-11-01 00:00:00', 85
2, '2023-11-01 00:00:00', 85,     '2023-11-02 00:00:00', 90
```

I planned to generate a date series between the start and end dates using 1 day as interval but could not generate the appropriate dates and hence can't further use lead or lag in it.
I have added the [fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/FouSXVbh).

Comment: Properly asked question. Upvoted!

Comment: I think Second row is wrong ! it should be `1 2023-10-28 00:00:00 55 2023-10-29 00:00:00 60`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to do it with the window functions `LAG()` and `LEAD()` :

```
with cte as (
  select t1.*, CASE WHEN start_time=date_strt THEN start_time ELSE date(start_time) END as start_time,
               lead(date(start_time), 1, date_end) over (partition by id order by start_time) as end_time
  from table1 t1
  cross join generate_series
        ( date_strt, date_end, '1 day'::interval) start_time
),
cte2 as (
  select c.id, c.start_time, c.strt_unit, 
         c.end_time, case when c.end_time = date_end then end_unit else unit end as end_value
  from cte c
  inner join table2 t on c.id = t.id and DATE(t.dates) = DATE(c.end_time)
)
select id, start_time,
       lag(end_value, 1, strt_unit) over (partition by id order by start_time) as start_value,
       end_time, end_value
from cte2;
```

Result :

```
id  start_time          start_value end_time            end_value
1   2023-10-27 12:00:00 5           2023-10-28 00:00:00 55
1   2023-10-28 00:00:00 55          2023-10-29 00:00:00 60
1   2023-10-29 00:00:00 60          2023-10-30 00:00:00 65
1   2023-10-30 00:00:00 65          2023-10-31 00:00:00 70
1   2023-10-31 00:00:00 70          2023-10-31 12:00:00 72
2   2023-10-30 12:15:00 78          2023-10-31 00:00:00 80
2   2023-10-31 00:00:00 80          2023-11-01 00:00:00 85
2   2023-11-01 00:00:00 85          2023-11-02 00:00:00 90
```

Explanations :

- First CTE used to generate ranges between two dates using `generate_series`
- The second CTE was used to link data with the second table in order to obtain the `end_value` for each range.
- The third CTE is used to obtain the `start_value` for each range.

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/lis0Wm0H)

Answer (score 0):

You can join `table2` with the previous `table2` and `table1` and the next `table2` and `table1`, making sure that there is nothing in between (this is why we join with the *_no_between tables and filter by the *_no_between tables being nulls) and then decide what's the proper value via `case`-`when`.

```
SELECT table2.id,
       CASE
           WHEN NOT (table2_previous.dates IS NULL) AND
                (table2_previous.dates > table1_previous.date_end)
           THEN table2_previous.dates
           WHEN NOT (table1_previous.date_end IS NULL)
           THEN table1_previous.date_end
           ELSE table2.dates
       END AS start_time,
       CASE
           WHEN NOT (table2_previous.dates IS NULL) AND
                (table2_previous.dates > table1_previous.date_end)
           THEN table2_previous.unit
           WHEN NOT (table1_previous.date_end IS NULL)
           THEN table1_previous.end_unit
           ELSE table2.unit
       END AS start_value,
       CASE
           WHEN NOT (table2_next.dates IS NULL) AND
                (table2_next.dates < table1_next.date_strt)
           THEN table2_next.dates
           WHEN NOT (table1_next.date_strt IS NULL)
           THEN table1_next.date_strt
           ELSE table2.dates
       END AS end_time,
       CASE
           WHEN NOT (table2_next.dates IS NULL) AND
                (table2_next.dates < table1_next.date_strt)
           THEN table2_next.unit
           WHEN NOT (table1_next.date_strt IS NULL)
           THEN table1_next.strt_unit
           ELSE table2.unit
       END AS end_value
FROM table2
LEFT JOIN table2 as table2_previous
ON table2.id = table2_previous.id AND table2.dates > table2_previous.dates
LEFT JOIN table2 as table2_previous_no_between
ON table2.id = table2_previous_no_between.id and table2_previous.dates < table2_previous_no_between.dates AND table2_previous_no_between.dates < table2.dates
LEFT JOIN table1 as table1_previous
ON table2.id = table1_previous.id AND table1_previous.date_end < table2.dates
LEFT JOIN table1 as table1_previous_no_between
ON table2.id = table1_previous_no_between.id AND table1_previous.date_end < table1_previous_no_between.date_end AND table1_previous_no_between.date_end < table2.dates
LEFT JOIN table2 as table2_next
ON table2.id = table2_next.id AND table2.dates < table2_next.dates
LEFT JOIN table2 as table2_next_no_between
ON table2.id = table2_next_no_between.id and table2_next.dates > table2_next_no_between.dates AND table2_next_no_between.dates > table2.dates
LEFT JOIN table1 as table1_next
ON table2.id = table1_next.id AND table1_next.date_strt > table2.dates
LEFT JOIN table1 as table1_next_no_between
ON table2.id = table1_next_no_between.id AND table1_next.date_end > table1_next_no_between.date_end AND table1_next_no_between.date_end > table2.dates
WHERE (table2_previous_no_between.id IS NULL) AND
      (table2_next_no_between.id IS NULL) AND
      (table1_previous_no_between.id IS NULL) AND
      (table1_next_no_between.id IS NULL)
```